# Terminal collapses when it get resized [video included]

Tags: command-line, 15.04

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCHCpOV-Kjk

After upgrade to 15.04 my terminal acting weird when i resize it, It collapses and never back to normal no matter what, i should close/re-open to get it back to normal, Any idea what cases this issue?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal` help?

Comment: No, Same thing.

Comment: OK, create a new user and log in as that user. Is the problem still there? If not, there's something with your user's settings. you could delete your `$HOME/.config/gnome-terminal` directory. That would delete any personal configuration files.

Comment: I did, and it worked fine in the default theme, It's only happen when i activate **Mbuntu-y-for-unity** theme.